# Convert Lat/Long into state

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, geocoding

I know how to set up geocode and pull the user's lat and long coordinates. However how do I turn this into a state name or code ie(DE, MO FL). I've looked at using Google's reverse geocode, but am unable to get an API code. Any other way to go about this?

Comment: Just use it :)  There are probably other options out there, but one way or another you are going to need a reverse geocode option.  What kind of usage limits do you think you'll be hitting? 2,500 per day is quite a few.  The business plan has 100,000 per day.

Comment: If you had a specific use case, I might be able to help come up with an option to cache or otherwise reduce the usage to avoid reaching these limits...

Comment: @Uxonith Sorry! I didn't mean actual usage limits, for some reason  their billing doesn't accept my payment and I can't get an API key :(. I worded it wrong, my bad!

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest the only way to achieve this is via reverse GeoCoding.

Here's a link to the API docs for reverse GeoCoding:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

And an anchored link to the outputs, clearly showing the state:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses

I've found some of the Google API docs somewhat confusing so I'd suggest searching for a worked example where someone has done something similar.